# How to force apt to download a specific version of a package from PPA?

Tags: apt

What I bascially want is to have the latest LibreOffice builds from this PPA: [libreoffice/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa)

Instead of the Maverick version I'd like to install this one: 1:3.4.4~rc1-0ubuntu1~ppa1

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The version you want to install was built on that PPA for Oneiric. You have a few options to try and get it working.

1. Manually add the oneiric version of that PPA then install
   regularly.  You would do this by creating a file (
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice.list ) and adding a line like

   `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main`

   This might not work if libreoffice needs to be built against some
   Maverick lib.
2. You could copy that version of the binary to your own PPA
   (launchpad has a copy feature for this) and have it rebuilt for
   maverick. This might not work if there are new dependencies that
   aren't satisfiable.
3. You could check the libreoffice website and see if they release a
   deb for it, although the version you specify is a release candidate
   so it may be more difficult to find there.
4. You could compile from source